# SonarQube Xamarin analysis on OSX

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, sonarqube

I've an OSX build server which I would like to analyse my Xamarin project.

The build server has Jenkins and Xamarin Studio installed.

I'm running SonarQube in a Docker container.

Can somebody help me with this, because the analysis does not detect .cs files. (And I have the C# plugin installed on SonarQube)

Comment: do you have news on that? I'm interested as well

Answer (score 0):

We could make Sonarqube and Xamarin work with the following lines. Replace `{token}` with your project's token.

```
cd MyProject.sln    
mono /Users/jenkins/Documents/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.4.2.1543-net46/SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"myProject" /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" /d:sonar.login="{token}"
msbuild /t:Rebuild
mono /Users/jenkins/Documents/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.4.2.1543-net46/SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:sonar.login="{token}"
```